# Where can I find CRM javascript object?

Tags: api, javascript

I want to use CRM.api3('Email', 'create', { ... call in my javascript. But the object CRM doesn't exist on my website. Which js file do I need to load to access that CRM object? I thought I'd load it with html tag <script src="...">

Comment: Which CMS and is this a "front-end" page or on a civi page? The civi resources don't always load on front-end pages and it seems to even be different for different CMS's.